# how to validate a cron expression using Later.js

Tags: javascript

I want to validate a cron expression using javascript. Here is a library that deals with cron expression http://bunkat.github.io/later/

From the documentation I am not able to found how to validate a cron expression. Whatever I am passing to `var cronSched = later.parse.cron('$%#');` Its always filling cronSched with an object. So How to get some true/false value for a cron expression?

Comment: later does not have the ability to validate cron expressions. It is very forgiving when parsing the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same needs and this tool appears to handle the job:

https://github.com/harrisiirak/cron-parser

Here is an solution, using lodash:

```
try{
    var validacao = cronParse.parseString(valor.cron);
    if (_.isEmpty(validacao.errors)){
        return true;
    }
    throw "Invalid Cron!"
}
catch(ex){
    return false;
}
```

Then you can test your return value to fullfill your needs. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: Can cron-parser be used with stand alone native JS or only with Node JS ?

Comment: I believe there is not any dependencies, so you can use wherever you like.

Answer (score -1):

The call `var cronSched = later.parse.cron('$%#');` returns a `later` schedule or throws an exception, so surround it with a `try { ... } catch (e) { ... }`, because it doesn't indicate which type the exceptions are.

Source: https://github.com/bunkat/later/blob/master/src/parse/cron.js